# If every continuous function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is constant then $A$ is Singleton?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, connectedness

> **Question**: given that, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and every continuous function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is constant,then $A$ is Singleton set? (true/false)

**My attempt**: what I know is, as $f$ is continuous and hence image of connected set under $f$ is connected set in $\mathbb{R}$. But from this information I am unable to solve this question!

Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't worry about connectivity.  Have you considered the fact that the distance to a fixed point is continuous?

Comment: If $A$ is not a singleton, you can easily define a non-constant continuous function. More generally, this is true if $A$ is any metric space.

Comment: You can project the first coordinate and that gives you a continuous function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (similar with the second coordinate).

Comment: Did get it sir, I think answer is true! But, unable to prove it formally :-(

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sir, how? if $A$ not singleton say, $A=\{(1, 0), (0, 1) \}$ then how can we define non constant continuous function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$? (Is because Every function on discrete space is continuous? ) on other hand if $A$ is not discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ say $A$ be set of all points inside and on the unit circle then, how can we define non constant continuous function? Further, this not a way of formal proof. How to prove formally that, $A$ is, Singleton? Please help

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is normal (e.g. metric) with at least two points then there will always be a non-constant continuous function $X\to\mathbb{R}$. Which is a consequence of Urysohn lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the idea of the coment, you can show that the maps

$p_1: A \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $ p_1(x,y) \to x$ is continuos, then if there are points on $A$ that difer in the first cordinate, this will be a non constant continuos map.

Let's say they all are of the form $(a,y)$.

Then lookin to $p_2: A \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $ p_2(x,y) \to y$ is continuos too, so the point in $A$ can't have diferent cordinates in the second entry etheir so they all must be equal to some fix $b$, but then there is only one point in $A$, $(a,b)$.

Comment: Nice approach sir. I got it! (We use the fact that, $p_1, p_2$ are continuous functions)

Comment: yeah showing that should not be complex using that a open set in $A$, is a open set in the space intersection $A$, so this is a proof that doesn't need a distance.

Comment: and may i add, that the proyection is continuos for every topological space that is a product, so this is very general.

Comment: (+1) Me andan robando puntos xd.

Comment: (Please disregard my last (now deleted) comment, it wasn't exactly wrong but sort of beside the point, in this context.)

Comment: @MW that is not correct, every funtion in the indiscrete topology is continuos because $f^-1(X) = A$ and $f^1(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ (if you mean the topology were only the empty set and all are open)

Comment: @FranAguayo I meant every continuous function from $X\times X\to\mathbb R$ is constant, which is sort of beside the point, since you are arguing (I think) that the projection $X\times X\to X$ is continuous. (Hence why I deleted).

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is a slight subtlety in whether the empty function on the empty set counts as a constant function.  If so, then $A$ can be the empty set.

Otherwise, $A$ is nonempty.  In that case, let $x_0\in A$, then the function $f\colon A\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=\|x-x_0\|$ is continuous.  It is therefore constant, and we have $f(x_0)=0$.

HINT: Given any $x\in A$, what is the value of $\|x-x_0\|$?

Can you conclude from here?

Comment: I didn't done it sir, my reputation (is just 35 yet, so I don't have privilege to downvote)

Comment: Sir, by Euclidean distance we have, $||x-x_0||=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2 + (y_1-y)^2}$ where $x_0=(x, y)$ and $x=(x_1, y_1)$

Comment: @GeneralMathematics without even using that, we have $\|x-x_0\|=f(x)=0$, since $f$ is constant and $f(x_0)=0$.  Now what does $\|x-x_0\|=0$ tell you about $x$ and $x_0$?

Comment: $x=x_0$ so $A$ is Singleton?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Precisely!  Every $x\in A$ satisfies $x=x_0$, so $A=\{x_0\}$.

Comment: But don't get it, without using Euclidean distance, how can we have $||x-x_0||= f(x) =0$?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics well at some level you are using the fact that the Euclidean distance function is continuous.  I just meant you didn't need to bother with the actual formula.  In other words, the fact that the function $f(x)=\|x-x_0\|$ is a continuous function is all you need, and the fact that $\|x-x_0\|=0$ if and only if $x=x_0$.

Comment: Sir, but we have $f$ is constant function. So we have $f(x) =||x-x_0||=k$ for some constant $k$. $k$ may not be zero! So how can we conclude $x=x_0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150232/discussion-between-m-w-and-general-mathematics).

Comment: Sir, how can we prove continuity of $f(x) =||x-x_0||$

Comment: @GeneralMathematics You can use triangle inequality to prove continuity.

Comment: @Tim how? Can you explain?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics $f(x)\leq \|x-y\| + f(y)$ and switch x and y